# Google Play app built using buildozer and vulnerable OpenSSL warning

Tags: android, openssl, google-play, buildozer

I have developed an app using kivy and built the apk file using buildozer. While releasing it on google play, I am getting the following error from google.

> Your app is using a version of OpenSSL containing a security
>   vulnerability. Please see this Google Help Center article for details,
>   including the deadline for fixing the vulnerability. Affects APK
>   version 1.

On forums, people ask to check the openssl version by running the following command

```
unzip -p MyApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"
```

The above command gave me blank result.

While packaging the apk, i used the following steps:

- buildozer android release
- sign and align using apksigner

Please note that the system on which I created the keyfile have OpenSSL 1.0.2f

I want to know how to fix this issue.

Comment: What is your question? Also see [Google Play and OpenSSL warning message](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24197777), [Android Google Play old OpenSSL warning](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36397094/608639), [How to grep or search .jar files for OpenSSL?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36213149) and [How to determine which dependency causes Google Play OpenSSL warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38187257)

Comment: This may apply as well: [Google Play warning and “unsafe implementation of X509TrustManager”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35604684/608639). We need to see the full message, and not an excerpt.