# OpenSSL version apk

Tags: android, android-studio, openssl

I have installed in iMac OpenSSL version 1.1.0d but when I build signed APK from Android Studio this APK is signed with OpenSSL version 1.0.1h.

In terminal console I run command `openssl version -a` and the result is the following:

```
OpenSSL 1.1.0d  26 Jan 2017
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
platform: darwin64-x86_64-cc
compiler: cc -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE
-DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5
-DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM
-DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPADLOCK_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM
-DOPENSSLDIR="\"/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/openssl-1.1.0d/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/local/
Cellar/openssl/openssl-1.1.0d/lib/engines-1.1\"" 
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/openssl-1.1.0d/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/openssl-1.1.0d/lib/engines-1.1"
```

I don't understand why Android Studio signed apk with 1.0.1h version of OpenSSL instead 1.1.0.d

Anybody knows because this occurs?

Thanks

Comment: Also see [Google Play and OpenSSL warning message](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24197777), [Android Google Play old OpenSSL warning](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36397094/608639), [Google Play warning and “unsafe implementation of X509TrustManager”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35604684/608639), [How to grep or search .jar files for OpenSSL?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36213149) and [How to determine which dependency causes Google Play OpenSSL warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38187257).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue about that. MetaIO SDK 6 was the problem. MetaIO uses OpenSSL 1.0.1h, for this reason, the apk is generated with this OpenSSL version.

No solution for that because MetaIO was discontinued and no new release is in the market. The solution is migrate to wikitude or vuforia SDK...