# "OpenSSL The vulnerabilities were addressed in OpenSSL 1.0.2f/1.0.1r

Tags: android, openssl, google-play

Google play has shown me a warning in one of the published apps 
https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6376725?hl=en

Someone could tell me how I can solve it

Comment: You should probably provide the text of the warning with your question. Also see [Google Play and OpenSSL warning message](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24197777), [Android Google Play old OpenSSL warning](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36397094/608639), [Google Play warning and “unsafe implementation of X509TrustManager”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35604684/608639), [How to grep or search .jar files for OpenSSL?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36213149) and [How to determine which dependency causes Google Play OpenSSL warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38187257)

Comment: It may be worth noting, OpenSSL 1.0.2 line is currently at OpenSSL 1.0.2L, not at 1.0.2F. If you are working on modern Android, you are likely using BoringSSL. I'm not sure if BoringSSL is following the same numbering scheme. BoringSSL used to provide the name OpenSSL even though it was a derivative work with modifications, and not OpenSSL proper.