# Google Play vulnerability warning for OpenSSL 1.0.2k

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl, google-play, android-security

When I submit new APK to Google Play, my APK is rejected with message:

> This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for
>   users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure.
>
> Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that
>   were detected in your recent submission. **Please upgrade your app(s)
>   as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded
>   APK.**
>
> **OpenSSL**
>
> The vulnerabilities were addressed in OpenSSL 1.02f/1.01r. To confirm
>   your OpenSSL version, you can do a grep search for:
>
> ```
> $ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"
> ```
>
> You can find more information and next steps in this [How to address
>   OpenSSL vulnerabilities in your
>   apps](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6376725).

I checked my APK, and it using 1.0.2k version of OpenSSL

**What should I do now?**

Comment: Also see [Google Play and OpenSSL warning message](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24197777), [Android Google Play old OpenSSL warning](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36397094/608639), [Google Play warning and “unsafe implementation of X509TrustManager”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35604684/608639), [How to grep or search .jar files for OpenSSL?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36213149) and [How to determine which dependency causes Google Play OpenSSL warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38187257)

Comment: [OpenSSL `1.0.2l` is the latest](https://www.openssl.org/source/) version available. Update your app to OpenSSL 1.0.2l.

Comment: i am use CURL library in NDK so how i can update this

Comment: Perhaps you should trying updating the NDK.

Answer (score 3):

Either you used OpenSSL directly yourself, or you are using some third-party library that is using OpenSSL.

If you used OpenSSL directly yourself, get a newer version.

If you are using some third-party library that is using OpenSSL, identify the library, then upgrade to the latest version of that library. If the library still uses the older OpenSSL, stop using that library.