# How to validate a public certificate against JVM trustStore

Tags: java, ssl, jvm, certificate

How can I validate a public certificate (one I have in file) against JVM trustStore without providing explicit link to ceacert file?

It's done e.g. by javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory 
(SSLPoke.java example here: https://gist.github.com/4ndrej/4547029)

---

Edited: I've changed original question after understanding better the problem and difference between trustStore and keyStore

Comment: The `cacerts` file *is* the default certificates file. Your citation doesn't say otherwise. It says there is no default *keystore.* Not the same thing. JSSE doesn't validate keys, it validates certificates. Your question really is not clear.

Comment: There is no default file for the _keystore_, there _is_ a default file for the _truststore_. If you _need_ to use the keystore, you must create your file and import your certificate into it. There is a ton of links to show you how to create your own keystore [one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-keytool-essentials-working-with-java-keystores) [two](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/07/java-keystore-tutorial.html), [three](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html)...

Comment: You should read about the difference between keystore and truststore. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6340918/372643) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/318441/372643), for example. In what context are you trying to verify your certificate? Are you making a connection to your server?

Comment: Thanks for replies, especially for links from Bruno.
I think the question should be: 
How can I validate a public certificate (one I have in file) against JVM trustStore without providing explicit link to **ceacert** file?

Comment: I believe here is answer for my question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6379434/4862240
Again thanks to @Bruno