# How to use SSL (certificate) in Android 4.0 WebView?

Tags: android, ssl, https, certificate

I tried to use SSL with Android 4.0.
I have a .pem files (cert, chain, fullchain and key) and I read tutorials explaining how do to it, but the file extensions are different (I do not even know the difference between them, I can not follow a .crt tutorial if I have other files).

I believe it is not necessary to post code because all are similar, I want old versions of Android TRUST in my certificate, the newer versions open my site normally, but older show no connection available.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfSYj.png

In navigators at top my website have a green certified HTTPS Let's Encrypty Authority X3.

I own the Portecle download and skills with leading programming languages, responsive sites, upload with webviews and etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trust Certificate Authority in WebView loadUrl()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349141/trust-certificate-authority-in-webview-loadurl)

Comment: I already saw this, the file extension is ".ca.crt" my file is other.

Comment: That is just a minor difference and only affects how you get the certificate into the trust store. You can just use [KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.org/) to build the trust store and include the trust store file in your app instead of the plain certificate. No need to generate the trust store at runtime like in the example.

Comment: Examine >> Examine SSL >> Set you domain in hierarchy >> Click at bottom button "PEM" and the text in textbox is my file content?

Comment: Where do I get my ca.crt? I tried as I explained above and it did not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329652/enabling-specific-ssl-protocols-with-android-webviewclient

SSL is no possible in Android < 4.1.3 really?

Comment: Throwing: "Falling back to SSLv3 because host is TLS intolerant: mysite.net:443"

Comment: XmlHttpRequest is a better solution?